# How can I delete keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to sync this intro with music. The problem is that there are two really fast keyframes that don't look good. I want to delete them but I can't figure out how.

*This is an image of the keyframes from the dope sheet. I want to delete the selected ones.*
 [image: http://prntscr.com/9y0fz1]

Answer (score 3):

To delete keyframes, select them, and press <kbd>X</kbd>.

Some keyframes may be locked (Icon of a lock on the side). I can't tell because the Nurbs or the Spiral are not expanded in the Dope Sheet Summary.

Comment: Hi, I tried to clean this up a bit. We need everything here to be really easy to read. Could you please look over it to make sure that this is consistent with what you said? I'm mostly concerned about my changing protected to locked, and saying that you can't tell. I thought that the can't might be a typo, but I want you to look over it just to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: Your are right. It is exactly what I wanted to say. I added "Dope Sheet Summary" to make clear, where to look for locked/protected keyframes.